# Google Sheets - Group/Aggregate data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

I would like a formula that groups/aggregates the data of Column A, B, C and D if column A is the same string

The issue is the end of the string in column A with different sizes at the end of the string - I have highlighted the ones I would like grouped to hopefully make it clearer

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zsSQD20IYM57hQNMoHscVDKgl3J1IMxPTcUwSpDgvEE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove sizes from names with `regexextract()` in cell `F1` like this:

`=arrayformula( iferror( regexextract(A1:A, "(.+?)-[\dA-Z]"), A1:A ) )`

Then query the data:

`=query(A1:F, "select F, sum(B), sum(C), avg(D) where F is not null group by F", 1)`

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zsSQD20IYM57hQNMoHscVDKgl3J1IMxPTcUwSpDgvEE/edit#gid=0).

Comment: That's definitely along the right lines thanks - This was a simplified extract of the data I am working with - I have included a couple of exact strings which are more complicated below on the spreadsheet if you wouldn't mind having a look at those

Essentially I would like all of the string apart from the data after the last ' - ' 

Thanks again

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). To learn how to adjust the regex, see [regularexpressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) and [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).